# Hausdorff measure a radon measure

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Can someone help me to prove that the Hausdorff measure is a Radon measure ([see here for Radon measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure))? I do not know how to start, so I would be thankful for some advice.

Comment: The $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $s < n$, is not finite...

Comment: Okay, thank you all for your answer. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^s$ is a (non trivial) Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $s=n$.